# What's wrong with the c++ code below?

Tags: c++, syntax

```
HRESULT SaveGraphFile(IGraphBuilder *pGraph, WCHAR *wszPath) 
{
    const WCHAR wszStreamName[] = L"ActiveMovieGraph"; 
    HRESULT hr;
    IStorage *pStorage = NULL;

    // First, create a document file that will hold the GRF file
    hr = StgCreateDocfile(
         wszPath,
         STGM_CREATE │ STGM_TRANSACTED │ STGM_READWRITE │ 
            STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE,
         0, &pStorage);
    ....
```

I copied it somewhere,but the compiler is reporting:

```
syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '│'
```

Why is `|` regarded an identifier ?

Comment: Seems fine to me; did you try narrowing it down? for example pass 0 for that argument and see what the compiler says. Maybe one of those `STGM_` constants are more than meets the eye?

Comment: Those constants are fine,all defined in `ObjBase.h` of WDK.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your pipes aren't really pipes. The character between the `STGM` constants should be `|` (ASCII 124), but what you have is `¦` (ASCII 166, which isn't strictly speaking ASCII at all). It looks like you're the victim of a faulty copy-paste.

Comment: But the pipe in my question seems to be `|`(ascii 124), isn't it?

Comment: No.  Pipe in your question: `│` vs. Ascii 124: `|`.  Side by side: `│|`

Comment: Found what you used: Extended Ascii 179, according to http://www.codesascii.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the constants one by one until all pipes are gone or put the expression with the constants in a variable of its own and use that instead.